# How to inject services into other services in Loopback JS?

Tags: loopback

New to Loopback framework.

I come from Angular and Java (Spring Framework), where a pattern like this is quite common.

How would I go about doing something similar in Loopback?

```js
@bind({ scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT })
export class EmailService {
  constructor(
    @service() public environmentService: EnvironmentService,
    @service() public logger: LoggingService,
    public transporter: Mail,
  ) {
    this.setupMailClient()
  }
}
```

This is the error I get when I try something like the above:

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ npm run build

> service-email@1.0.0 build /Users/clementoh/projects/service-email
> lb-tsc

$ node -r source-map-support/register .
Server is running at http://[::1]:3000/development/v1/emails
Try http://[::1]:3000/development/v1/emails/ping
Unhandled error in POST /verifications/email: 500 ResolutionError: The argument 'LoggingService.constructor[1]' is not decorated for dependency injection but no value was supplied by the caller. Did you forget to apply @inject() to the argument? (context: RequestContext-x2a2BH0zTmy5OlakULzpvw-3, resolutionPath: controllers.RemoteConfigController --> @RemoteConfigController.constructor[0] --> services.EmailService --> @EmailService.constructor[1] --> services.LoggingService)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @lorenzoli for pointing me in the right direction.

The reason why I got an error was because I was using a TypeScript feature to automatically create class-level properties when they're defined in the constructor.

```
@bind({scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT})
export class EmailService {
  constructor(public transporter: Mail) {
    this.setupMailClient()
  }
}
```

When I removed the property from the constructor, everything worked as expected.

I guess with Loopback, we shouldn't use that automatic property creation syntax from TypeScript that is commonly seen in Angular projects.

```
@bind({scope: BindingScope.TRANSIENT})
export class EmailService {
  public transporter: Mail

  constructor() {
    this.setupMailClient()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for inject service is the following:

```
constructor(
    @service(MyService) public myService: MyService
) {}
```

Try it, if it isn't working again you need to bind your service on Application Context, for example inside application.ts (or on your Application constructor):

```
import {MyService} from './services';

constructor(options = ApplicationConfig = {}) {
    super(options);

    // Setup
    this.bind('services.my-service').toClass(MyService);
}
```

Now you can inject your service via previously or from this:

```
@inject('services.my-service) public myService: MyService
```

Comment: Thanks @lorenzoli for pointing me in the right direction. I found the root cause for my error and posted an answer for it. I will upvote your answer nevertheless :)